# Is there any Plone addon to control the username constraints?

Tags: plone

I'm looking for an addon to control the registration process over username constraints.

For example I would like to force lowercase in username.

If it can apply also this kind of contraint to the password it should be perfect.

(I ask before starting to develop it)

Answer (score 0):

Products.LoginLockout contains some (crude) code and checks. LoginLockout is implemented as PAS plugin.

Comment: this plugin seems to contains only authentication related features, no user adding stuff. Wrong ?